# Error when obtaining token

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying the sample code `NativeClient-Headless-DotNet.sln` against my B2C tenant.

When I attempt to execute the command:

```
result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientId, uc).Result;
```

using an existing username and password, I get this exception:

```
InnerException = {"unknown_user_type: Unknown User Type"}
```

As far as I know, I've set-up all the values correctly in Web and App config (I'm using the same values that I use in my Graph API project, which works OK).

Any ideas why this should happen?
Are accounts created with:

```
userType.type = "userName";
```

found by this method?

Comment: Do you require a "headless" client to log in to the B2C tenant or do you want to log the B2C users in to a desktop or other native client?

Comment: Isn't that the same thing? What I'm trying to do is authenticate a User without using the usual web page that she signs in with, so that the entire log-in process is handled within my desktop application code (no web browser).

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Azure AD B2C doesn't have any direct support for this.

However, work to [support for the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13817784-add-support-for-resource-owner-password-credential) in Azure AD B2C is in-progress.

This new feature will enable a desktop application to collect a user credential and POST it to the B2C tenant for validation.

Comment: Chris, Thanks for the link. If B2C doesn't support this, why did Microsoft create the 'NativeClient-Headless-DotNet.sln' I downloaded?

Comment: This NativeClient-Headless-DotNet sample is purposed for an Azure AD (Enterprise) directory rather than a B2C one.

Comment: Thanks Chris. This page "https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless" doesn't make that distinction clear.